# Facebook embeded video with iframe not working

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

> we were embedding facebook videos in our website using iframe, it was working fine before, but from last few days site is not able to load video. we have tried it with simple web page as well but no luck. below is the code we are using

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=video_id" width="650" height="400" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

please let me know if anyone can do a quick help

Comment: When embedding videos, privacy applies, try embedding a public video

Answer (score 8):

Just Use this link. It worked for me.  "http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX"; 
where XXXXXXXX is your facebook video id.
eg:
Facebook Sample Video:

```html
 <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10152463995718183" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Comment: please add some content from the link

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this link now :)
https://m.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=xxxxxxxx

OLD ANSWER
the problem isnt that the video is not embeded but that it is not in an iframe correctly stretched. Cca a week before facebook has changed the embed link and video is not stretch to screen width and it cant be done in this fashion. I havent find a solution how to fix it yet.

Maybe there is a possibility to gut out mobile version of the video which is even in HTML5 ... problem with that approach is that the video is available only for a limited amount of time (cca 2 hours) .. then the link will expire and you need to click on a facebook video again which will create a different video.

Example here - https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=751234308276798&id=643601645706732&_rdr

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this URL: https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/plugins/video.php?allowfullscreen=true&autoplay=true&container_width=800&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fredbull%2Fvideos%2F10155801793140352%2F&locale=en_US&sdk=joey

It's better then the embed url. The video fits in viewport.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to embed different video? the video you're trying to embed may have been remove or hide so it can't show on your site. try embeding a sample video. if it appear the problem is on your video.

Comment: yes i have tried different videos but not working for me.can you give me an working example?

Comment: The above code seems to work fine...Here is an example  ..... <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=754295507939962" width="650" height="400" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>.........There must be issue with privacy as @Adam Azad commented above