# Embedded facebook video not working in safari

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, safari

I have a simple page with this HTML code :

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=395974580579165" 
        width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

It is working fine in chrome but not in safari. I only have the preview with safari, but I cannot play the video.

However, a youtube embedded video in an iframe work both on chrome and safari

Any idea ? What is the correct way to embed a facebook video ?

**Safari version : 8.0.2 (10600.2.5)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of Facebook embedded video requires flash player, which is not installed by default with Safari.

The problem is that Safari fails silently and doesn't even ask the user to install the plug-in. So I had no clue...

Answer (score 0):

The embedded link for facebook looks something like this:

https://m.facebook.com/video/your-video.php?v=12345

Have a look at this post:
[Facebook embeded video with iframe not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479957/facebook-embeded-video-with-iframe-not-working)

It gives you more insight. Hope this helps

Comment: I came across this answer already. It lowers the video ratio and shows nothing in safari. This is worse actually

Comment: which version of safari are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Bring up the Adobe Flash Settings page with this link http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html then starting at Global Privacy Settings, compare a working browser (e.g. Chrome) to the non working one (Safari in my case).

In my case, I had locked down Flash too much in Safari (restricting e.g. storage space allowed in the browser) to the extent that Facebook videos just appeared as a black space with no error message. Just wouldn't play back.

But adjusting the settings to those of the working Chrome Flash plugin re-enabled Flash video (Safari / Mac OSX) for me.