# How to play facebook in iframe using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, iframe

I tried to use javascript play facebook video from iframe but not work.

How can i do ?

```html
<div onclick="play_fn()">
click here to play
</div>
<br>
<script>
function play_fn(){
    $(#vid).play();
}
</script>

<iframe id="vid" width="560" height="315" 
  style="border:none;overflow:hidden" 
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true" src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10157271716931509">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479957/facebook-embeded-video-with-iframe-not-working

Comment: @webmentor.com -  i not see any answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly run a facebook video on the site you need to do an API request

Go through

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/